# Casting a structure type included in the sizeof

Tags: c

I have a function which accepts the size mentioned as an argument like :

```
 sizeof(tcpstuct) * tcprules
```

Lets say

tcpstuct is a structure having type INT32 members . ( INT32 is of type int ,defined as INT32 due to platform dependency)

tcprules is a variable of  type NAT32 .

If the function accepts another type say WORD32 . How should the cast go about ?

What I have tried :

```
(WORD32 ) (sizeof(tcpstuct) * (INT32 )tcprules )
(WORD32 ) ((INT32 )(sizeof(tcpstuct) * (INT32 )tcprules ))
```

But both of these throws in seg fault ! Do I need to cast the `sizeof` ?

EDIT : As all have pointed out , Seg fault was due to a bug elsewhere else thanks gdb

Comment: Do you know that the casting preserves the values as you intended?

Comment: It's not the casting itself that causes the segmentation fault, but something else. I suggest you run your program in a debugger (it should be your first reaction when getting a sefault). It will help you locate the crash, and also let you examine variables to help you understand why it crashed.

Comment: "tcpstuct is a structure of type INT32" - I don't know what this means. Is `tcpstuct` an object, or a type? If it's an object, then it can't be a structure if it has type `int`. If it's a type, then what does it mean to say that it's "of type INT32"?

Comment: `INT32` is an `int`, what is `WORD32`, A `long`? What about `NAT32`, is that a `long` as well?

Answer (score 1):

If `sizeof(tcpstuct)` is the size of one "thingy", and `tcprules` is the number of "thingies", then there should be no need for any casts.

`C` automatically converts between different integer types, so whatever type your expression `sizeof(tcpstuct) * tcprules` has, should be converted to `WORD32` (whatever that is, but assuming it's an integer type).

It's likely that the bug in your code is elsewhere, and very unlikely that this expression causes a segfault in any of the versions you've posted. Maybe the segfault is in the function you call.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any potential crash in your statements. The segfault must be somewhere else.